# Scope of Variables in Java

Tags: java, list, variables, scope

In a Java Class, I have three List as fields in a class.
So I believe I made them available to the whole class? and all *inner* classes?

However, this does not work:
(For the example, I will only show one list here, not all three)

```
class Items extends ListActivity {

List<String> items = null;  // field

Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // stuff

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    new Task().execute();

    Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(items.size()));



 }

 class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    // in this subclass, I parse items from JSON and add to List "items".

     items = add(item);

 }
```

Once I exit the task, I seem to lose the items in the List.  It Logs "size 0";  if I do it inside the task, it shows the proper amount of items.  Am I missing a very basic point about the scope of List variables here?

EDIT:  Below is the complete Task class (slightly cleaned up for posting)

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    private InputStream is = null;
    private String result = "";


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url_select = "items.php";

        param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", Category));

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = json_data.getString("item");

                items.add(item);

                Log.d("Items", item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No items!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is task an inner class of Items ?

Comment: If your task does things asynchronously, your log message probably gets printed before your task is done with its work. `Log.d` probably occurs immediately, while `new task().execute();` may take awhile. It's hard to tell what's happening based on your question and code, but I'm inferring that a class that extends `AsyncTask` performs tasks asynchronously...

Comment: can you fix your code - it isnt clear whether task is an inner class (you state subclass, but the `extends` doesnt show that  - also, where is the statement `items = add(item)`, it needs to be within a method or similar.  One more - can you clarify if `onCreate` is called from a constructor?

Comment: I have added the add(item) in context.

Comment: And yes, this is an inner class.  I apologize on that blatant error.

Comment: Well, I finally figured it out with your help.  I have three tasks.  At the end of the third one, I put in all my data needs as far as my Adapter for the list I am creating.  Because it is doing it Asynchronously, I needed to just do this at the end, not the same time.  I know I didn't explain that good, but basically, you each provided me with a little something to figure this one out!

Comment: Dude, you might want to follow conventions. Capitalize your classes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not Android developer but isn't `AsyncTask` something like new Thread? If yes then you just see "size 0" because `Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(items.size()));` was executed before `new task().execute();` updated your list.

Comment: You are completely correct.  It is a new thread.  And the Log did show that before. You just gave me a reason why now. good to know!

Comment: BTW is your `class task` inner class? If yes then it (just like methods) have access to all fields of "parent" class, even private ones, so changing visibility of list is irrelevant to your question :)

Comment: Yes it is inner; my fault!  BAD mistake in words.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read through this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Basically, the default access level is `package private` (I could be wrong on the description), but basically it means that so long as you're in the same package you can see the member, but it is not visible to sub classes.

Try using the `protected` access level instead

Comment: I, personally, always mark my class members as `public`, `protected` or `private`, but that's just me

Comment: Well, I did add protected before the fields and the list still shows at size 0 outside of the sub class... I will take look at the link. (for what its worth, I added public and nothing.  maybe In the subclass I should be calling "Items.this" (Items is the class name) or something?

Comment: How does the execute method work?  Is it spawning off a new thread?  If so, the log message will always be 0.  Also, the new task has no scope context to the list member, they don't share the same memory space.  If you're REALLY serious about working this way, you either need to supply the list as a parameter to the task or make the list static

Comment: ok, you're right, I will need to redo this.  I have 3 tasks.  All three connect to three different php files to populate the lists from MySql.  So I will have to find a way to keep the lists in scope together when I set the Adapter.  Will mark as correct since this can't be done.